# Extra Icon on NavigationToolbar2QTAgg

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have recently used a solution found in StackOverflow to remove icons on the Toolbar, however, I cannot remove one and I do not know why. I was wondering if anyone has seen and removed this extra icon successfully. The answer I used was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549675

This is how I used it:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar

class NavigationToolbar(NavigationToolbar):
    # only display the buttons we need
    toolitems = [t for t in NavigationToolbar.toolitems if
                 t[0] in ('Pan', 'Zoom', 'Save')]
```

And the extra icon looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG0Ll.png

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py#L586 for where that icon is added.  It is done outside of the `toolitem` list, hence why this method didn't work.

Adding

```
matplotlib.backends.backend_qt.figureoptions = None
```

will do what you want.