# Keep pan on by default in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I've integrated `matplotlib` in tkinter and I want to keep the pan button on by default and then [hide the pan button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779944/how-to-remove-toolbar-buttons-from-matplotlib)

```
NavigationToolbar2.toolitems = (
    ('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'),
    ('Back', 'Back to  previous view', 'back', 'back'),
    ('Forward', 'Forward to next view', 'forward', 'forward'),
    (None, None, None, None),
    ('Pan', 'Pan axes with left mouse, zoom with right', 'move', 'pan'),
    # ('Subplots', 'Configure subplots', 'subplots', 'configure_subplots'),
    (None, None, None, None),
    ('Save', 'Save the figure', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
  )
```

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple code.
First remove unwanted buttons, in our case "Pan" and then enter "Pan" mode.

I used [this page](https://newdevzone.com/posts/how-to-remove-toolbar-buttons-from-matplotlib) as a source for my answer (how to remove button).

This works for TK based GUI (your case):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import backend_bases

backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2.toolitems = (
    ('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'),
    ('Back', 'Back to  previous view', 'back', 'back'),
    ('Forward', 'Forward to next view', 'forward', 'forward'),
    (None, None, None, None),
    ('Save', 'Save the figure', 'filesave', 'save_figure'),
)

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(t, s)
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='Example plot')
ax.grid()

# Enter "pan" mode
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.pan()

plt.show()
```

---

This works for QT based GUI:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Remove unwanted buttons
toolbar = plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolbar
unwanted_buttons = ['Pan']
for x in toolbar.actions():
    if x.text() in unwanted_buttons:
        toolbar.removeAction(x)

ax.plot(t, s)
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='Example plot')
ax.grid()

# Enter "pan" mode
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.pan()

plt.show()
```